# Expressing an inequality in interval notation

Tags: calculus

How would I express this inequality in interval notation?

[image]

I am trying to find the domain of this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-7<x<7$ becomes $x\in(-7,7)$

$x<-7 \vee x>7$ becomes $x\in(-\infty,-7)\cup(7,\infty)$

Comment: Turns out its a union with the 1st and second intervals thanks for the help!